# metro apps - 3D transformation of 2D controls using C#

Tags: c#, 3d, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am creating a metro app using C# and want a 2D block to swivel around in 3D space, much like in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh673529(v=vs.85).aspx

However, the link above uses CSS3 and Javascript and I want to do this using C# and the APIs allowed for metro apps. I know there are libraries, like http://thriple.codeplex.com/releases/view/24393, that can do this for WPF apps but I don't think they will work for metro apps.

Has anyone attempted to do something similar to this or have any references?

Comment: Developer preview missing XAML perspective transform for some reason. Hopefully MS will bring it back in beta. It could be that MS crippling XAML/C# development to force switch to HTML/Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Projection". See [windows.ui.xaml.media.planeprojection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.planeprojection.aspx)

Example: `grid.Projection = new PlaneProjection() { RotationY = 45 };`